# Used "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data" but my bookmarks and extensions disapeared

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

I was trying to solve an annoying problem with **THIS WEB PAGE IS NOT AVAILABLE** message showing up all the time in my CHROME browser. I followed indeed ALL the forums advises on the issue to no avail. Till I found this procedure at START: to use "**%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data**", rename the DEFAULT as BACKUPDEFAULT folder,close the directory and see if the problem was solved. Which it was instantly !!! and my browser speed up as never before. **But my bookmarks and extensions had dissapeared**. Now I don't know how to retrieve my bookmarks, extensions and the rest of the configuration in my browser without coming back to the  WEB PAGE IS NOT AVAILABLE  disturbance.

Thank you very much indeed for your help,

Fernando

Samsung R 530
Windows 7 500 gigs

Comment: If you didn't backup your profile before you did this, then your only hope, is to recover the file using file recover software of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

- Go back to "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data" and delete the new "Default" profile you made.
- Rename your backed-up profile "BACKUPDEFAULT" back to "Default" (or just copy it).
- Go into Chrome, and [export your bookmarks](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en), etc. to a file.
- Close Chrome.
- Go back and repeat what you did before to create a new Default profile.
- Load Chrome again.
- [Import](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en) the stuff you exported.

As for extensions, I'd just leave them all out and only install them again as you need them.  There's a good chance it was one of your extensions that was causing the problems you were seeing, so installing them one at a time as needed will give you a better chance of identifying a potential culprit if it starts acting up again.

Comment: Thank you Techie007 for your quick answer!!! I am a little nervous renaming in a wong way. I just took a look again inside "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data" and I found 3 folders:

Comment: Thank you Techie007 for your quick answer!!! I am a little nervous renaming in a wong way. I just took a look again inside "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data" and I found 3 folders: One folder named User Data ; one folder named User Data\Backup default and one folder named User Data\Default

Comment: You can simply copy your needed files from your `User Data\Backup default` folder to your `User Data\Default` folder. The files you will need are: `Bookmarks`, `Current Session`, `Current Tabs`, `History`, `History-journal`, `History Provider Cache`, `Last Tabs`, `Last Session`, `Login Data` and `Login Data-journal`. These will copy the most normally needed settings to your new `Default` profile.